# Issue on Using Animate.css - Horizontal Scrollbar Added to Page on Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to add some animations to text using `Animate.css` and `jQuery` @ [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3126/)

I am using jquery `addClass()` to apply `.animated`, `.bounceInLeft`, and `.bounceInRight` to the elements by using this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#solu-title-1').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('#solu-title-2').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
    $('#solu-description-1').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('#solu-description-2').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
});
```

but as you can see the page also is getting annoying  `Horizontal Scrollbar` during the animation process. Can you please let me know how I can stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3127/

Answer (score 5):

Actyally, better set like here:

```
html, body{ overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 100%}
```

Because for mobile versions it doesn't work corectly

Answer (score 1):

I solved this adding a metatag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Do not do this. It creates an inaccessible experience for people who need to zoom in order to view and use your site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - I finally found because I used some animations in React Spring(fade in from right), which caused scrolling down the page to feel like a slip n slide.
I added “user-scalable=no” to the html viewport metatag, as commented above, and it did the trick for me!